# In one time both menus are active

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: image of nav bar]i put JQuery in my footer, it's having bug like when i click on notes home and notes both section get active please help any on

```
<script>
    $(function () {
         setNavigation();
    });

    function setNavigation() {
        var path = window.location.pathname;
        path = path.split('/');
        path = path[path.length-1];

        $(".menu--iris .navbar-nav li a").each(function () {
            var href = $(this).attr('href');
            href = href.split('/');
            href = href[href.length-1];

            if (path === href) {
                $(this).parent('li').addClass('menu__item--current');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Show the html also?

Comment: You can inspect it website is live https://easyfreenotes.in/

Comment: Ok. The home always active... I think it is something you need to handle from backend? Is this WP?

Comment: I don't see you removing the active class from the previous active element

Comment: @jackjop But it always sticks with `Home`.. others are fine.. Wherever u click Home is always active.

Comment: from HTML, find the Home li element and delete the precoded active class

Comment: @jackjop If it can be fixed from server side code, then this JS hack not needed.

Comment: it's hard to say before seeing your html or backend code. I would guess you have `menu__item--current` class in your Home element. that's why it stays there. removing the previous active class also would work

Comment: Working fine, i just removed active class with the click li .

Comment: @shankarsingh please accept one of the answers so this question can be closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code and replace your home page list item in header file.

```
<li class="menu__item"><a href="your link here" class="menu__link">Home</a></li>
```

If you need any help let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

your HTML for the HOME link looks like:

```
<li class="menu__item menu__item--current">
  <a href="https://easyfreenotes.in/index.php/Site" class="menu__link">Home</a>
</li>
```

the `menu__item--current` class is hardcoded here, inserted in PHP file. As @VSM and @jackjop correctly noticed, you should remove this class and let jQuery to decide where to add it:

```
<li class="menu__item">
  <a href="https://easyfreenotes.in/index.php/Site" class="menu__link">Home</a>
</li>
```

you can also remove this hardcoded class in your JS code:

```
$(".menu--iris .navbar-nav li.menu__item--current").removeClass('menu__item--current');
$(".menu--iris .navbar-nav li a").each(function () {
  ...
});
```

BUt the best solution I think would be to print this class in your PHP code (since you already do it for the HOME link)

also, I noticed that you have a trailing slash in your Easy Notes image link:

```
<h1>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://easyfreenotes.in/index.php/Site/">
    <i>E</i>
    <span>asy-Notes</span>
  </a>
</h1>
```

I would recommend to remove this slash:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="https://easyfreenotes.in/index.php/Site">
```

because, your jquery code checks only last fragment of your URL against HREF, so `/index.php/Site/` may be equal to `/index.php/Site/paper/`